# plotly graph not rendering in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, plotly, jinja2

Plotly version = '5.12.0'
Jinja2 version = '3.1.2'

I am creating some visuals for a HTML report in python and then emailing them to relevant people. I am using redmail to send the emails.

I am creating a graph using plotly and then converting it to html. This is the code to recreate the graph and produce the html output.

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
from redmail import EmailSender
import jinja2

fig =px.scatter(x=range(10), y=range(10))
graph = fig.to_html(full_html = False, include_plotlyjs ='cdn')
```

I am then inserting this into my Jinja HTML template which looks as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html> 
    <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script> 
    {{graph}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, I send the email to the relevant parties using this code

```
email = EmailSender(
    host='smtp.gmail.com',
    port=587,
    username='email@gmail.com',
    password=pwd
)

email.set_template_paths(
    html="",
    text="",
)

# Create an env
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(''))

email.templates_html = jinja_env
email.templates_text = jinja_env

email.send(
    subject="An example email",
    sender="example@gmail.com",
    receivers=['example@live.co.uk'],
    html_template='template_file.html',
    body_params= {'graph':graph}
)
```

The problem is, when I receive the email, it is completely blank, with no data/visuals in it. I should expect to see the plotly scatter plot, or at the minimum the raw text of the plotly graph html.

I have tried pasting the div elements stored in the `graph` variable into an online HTML viewer, and the graph appears. I have seen other posts suggesting adding `{{graph|safe}}` to the graph variable in the jinja template, but that does not work either.

I am completely lost as why it is not appearing/rendering in the Jinja template. It is not a problem with redmail as I have used it in the past for other templating work and have managed to insert HTML tables successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the output of the `graph` variable outputted by `plotly.to_html()`

```
<div>                        <script type="text/javascript">window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: \'local\'};</script>\n        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.17.1.min.js"></script>                <div id="6a72d392-1672-450b-9d7f-5ad0cd478fd4" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>            <script type="text/javascript">                                    window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};                                    if (document.getElementById("6a72d392-1672-450b-9d7f-5ad0cd478fd4")) {                    Plotly.newPlot(                        "6a72d392-1672-450b-9d7f-5ad0cd478fd4",                        [{"hovertemplate":"x=%{x}<br>y=%{y}<extra></extra>","legendgroup":"","marker":{"color":"#636efa","symbol":"circle"},"mode":"markers","name":"","orientation":"v","showlegend":false,"x":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"xaxis":"x","y":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"yaxis":"y","type":"scatter"}],                        {"legend":{"tracegroupgap":0},"margin":{"t":60},"template":{"data":{"barpolar":[{"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"barpolar"}],"bar":[{"error_x":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"error_y":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"bar"}],"carpet":[{"aaxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"baxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"type":"carpet"}],"choropleth":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"type":"choropleth"}],"contourcarpet":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"type":"contourcarpet"}],"contour":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"type":"contour"}],"heatmapgl":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"type":"heatmapgl"}],"heatmap":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"type":"heatmap"}],"histogram2dcontour":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"type":"histogram2dcontour"}],"histogram2d":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"type":"histogram2d"}],"histogram":[{"marker":{"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"histogram"}],"mesh3d":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"type":"mesh3d"}],"parcoords":[{"line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"parcoords"}],"pie":[{"automargin":true,"type":"pie"}],"scatter3d":[{"line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"scatter3d"}],"scattercarpet":[{"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"scattercarpet"}],"scattergeo":[{"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"scattergeo"}],"scattergl":[{"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"scattergl"}],"scattermapbox":[{"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"scattermapbox"}],"scatterpolargl":[{"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"scatterpolargl"}],"scatterpolar":[{"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"scatterpolar"}],"scatter":[{"fillpattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2},"type":"scatter"}],"scatterternary":[{"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"type":"scatterternary"}],"surface":[{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"type":"surface"}],"table":[{"cells":{"fill":{"color":"#EBF0F8"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"header":{"fill":{"color":"#C8D4E3"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"type":"table"}]},"layout":{"annotationdefaults":{"arrowcolor":"#2a3f5f","arrowhead":0,"arrowwidth":1},"autotypenumbers":"strict","coloraxis":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"colorscale":{"diverging":[[0,"#8e0152"],[0.1,"#c51b7d"],[0.2,"#de77ae"],[0.3,"#f1b6da"],[0.4,"#fde0ef"],[0.5,"#f7f7f7"],[0.6,"#e6f5d0"],[0.7,"#b8e186"],[0.8,"#7fbc41"],[0.9,"#4d9221"],[1,"#276419"]],"sequential":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"sequentialminus":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]},"colorway":["#636efa","#EF553B","#00cc96","#ab63fa","#FFA15A","#19d3f3","#FF6692","#B6E880","#FF97FF","#FECB52"],"font":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"geo":{"bgcolor":"white","lakecolor":"white","landcolor":"#E5ECF6","showlakes":true,"showland":true,"subunitcolor":"white"},"hoverlabel":{"align":"left"},"hovermode":"closest","mapbox":{"style":"light"},"paper_bgcolor":"white","plot_bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","polar":{"angularaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","radialaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"scene":{"xaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","gridwidth":2,"linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white"},"yaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","gridwidth":2,"linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white"},"zaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","gridwidth":2,"linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white"}},"shapedefaults":{"line":{"color":"#2a3f5f"}},"ternary":{"aaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"baxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","caxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"title":{"x":0.05},"xaxis":{"automargin":true,"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","zerolinewidth":2},"yaxis":{"automargin":true,"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","zerolinewidth":2}}},"xaxis":{"anchor":"y","domain":[0.0,1.0],"title":{"text":"x"}},"yaxis":{"anchor":"x","domain":[0.0,1.0],"title":{"text":"y"}}},                        {"responsive": true}                    )                };                            </script>        </div>
```